# How to stack two matrices horizontally in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, stack

In python I need to stack two matrices horizontally.

Initial matrices I have:

```
a = [[3, 5]
     [8, 6]
     [9, 2]]

b = [[4]
     [1]
     [7]]
```

What I am able to do:

```
import numpy as np
c = np.hstack((a, b))
c = [[3, 5, 4]
     [8, 6, 1]
     [9, 2, 7]]
```

What I need:

```
c = [[3, 5], [4]
     [8, 6], [1]
     [9, 2], [7]]
```

Comment: Aren't you missing commas in the definition of `a` and `b`?

Comment: Have you written the output correctly? I am guessing you would need something like this: `[ [[3, 5], [4]], [[8, 6], [1]], [[9, 2], [7]] ]` (a 3d matrix)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with two lists:

```
In [83]: a = [[3, 5], 
    ...:      [8, 6], 
    ...:      [9, 2]] 
    ...:  
    ...: b = [[4], 
    ...:      [1], 
    ...:      [7]]                                                              
In [84]:
```

Make a new list with zip:

```
In [84]: [[i,j] for i,j in zip(a,b)]                                            
Out[84]: [[[3, 5], [4]], [[8, 6], [1]], [[9, 2], [7]]]
```

and if it must be an array:

```
In [85]: np.array(_, object)                                                    
Out[85]: 
array([[list([3, 5]), list([4])],
   [list([8, 6]), list([1])],
   [list([9, 2]), list([7])]], dtype=object)
```

That shape is (3,2).

Or make an array of the right shape and dtype and assign values:

```
In [87]: arr = np.empty((3,2),object)                                           
In [88]: arr[:,0] = a                                                           
In [89]: arr[:,1] = b                                                           
In [90]: arr                                                                    
Out[90]: 
array([[list([3, 5]), list([4])],
       [list([8, 6]), list([1])],
       [list([9, 2]), list([7])]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using map:

```
# Append each element of a and b:
[*map(lambda x: [a[x], b[x]],  [*range(0, len(a))])]
```

Using a list comprehension:

```
[a[i]+[b[i]] for i in range(0, len(a))]
```

Using a for loop:

```
lst = [] * len(a)
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    lst.append(a[i]+[b[i]])
print(lst)
```

Data:

```
# Data: 
a = [[3, 5], [8, 6], [9, 2]]
b = [[4], [1], [7]]
```